# Are there alternative (other than XML library) ways to parse XML file in R?

Tags: r, xml

There are reasons why I cannot use `XML` package. I have a code using `XML` library. However, is it possible somehow to rewrite the code for rows below `# XML package` and still get the same results? Unfortunately, I cannot add a reproducible example using `dput` of the `XML`, as it does not show anything to copy and paste here.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/nuest/3ed3b0057713eb4f4d75d11bb62f2d66), I found a link that shows how alternatively xml2 package can be used, but not for all functions.

```
#read url
url <- "https://transparency.entsoe.eu/api?securityToken=xxxx&documentType=A82&BusinessType=A96&controlArea_Domain=10YFI-1--------U&periodStart=202206020000&periodEnd=202206040000"

# find subset for timeseries
myXMLts_up <- xml_child(myXMLfile, search = 13, ns = xml_ns(myXMLfile)) 

# find subset for position/quantity data
myXMLpts_up <- xml_child(myXMLts_up, search = 7, ns = xml_ns(myXMLts_up))


# XML package
myXML  <- xmlTreeParse(my_data ,asText = TRUE, useInternal = TRUE)

myXML  <- xmlRoot(myXML )

# convert to dataframe
myXMLdf  <- xmlToDataFrame(myXML )
```

Comment: Can you share the url? Maybe package [`rvest`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rvest), *Wrappers around the 'xml2' and 'httr' packages to make it easy to download, then manipulate, HTML and XML* can do the job.

Comment: I added url, additionally, I was trying to convert it to the list and then do manipulating. However, xmlToList() is also from XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with package [`rvest`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rvest). The package title is

> Wrappers around the 'xml2' and 'httr' packages to make it easy to download, then manipulate, HTML and XML.

The code is self-explanatory.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(rvest)
  library(dplyr)
})

url <- "https://transparency.entsoe.eu/api?documentType=A82&BusinessType=A96&controlArea_Domain=10YFI-1--------U&periodStart=202206020000&periodEnd=202206040000"

myXMLfile <- read_html(url)

position <- myXMLfile %>%
  html_elements("position") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.integer

quantity <- myXMLfile %>%
  html_elements("quantity") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.integer

myXMLdf <- data.frame(position, quantity)
head(myXMLdf)
#>   position quantity
#> 1        1        0
#> 2        2        0
#> 3        3        0
#> 4        4       80
#> 5        5       80
#> 6        6       80
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi, yes it is working. Thank you very much. Could you delete the securityToken from the link I added? And could you tell how to get "flowdirection.direction", I tried html_elements("flowdirection.direction"), but it did not work out

Comment: @PriitMets Security token deleted. But beware, SO users with reputation high enough to have edit privileges can see what was deleted.

Comment: thanks, at least it is not public. could you help how to get html_elements("flowdirection.direction")? it seems that dot in the name makes this function not working properly